# Why is the output displayed as an empty dataframe in my scraping code for Zara products?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data to understand a trend. Below is the scraping code. But I'm getting the output as an empty dataframe. I'm not sure where I am going wrong in the approach.

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title, Price, Discount]
Index: []
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# Specify the full path to the ChromeDriver executable
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.zara.com/us/en/search?searchTerm=women%20jackets&section=WOMAN')
driver.maximize_window()

container=driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//ul[contains(@class, "product-grid__product-list")]')
products=container.find_elements(by='xpath', value='.//li[contains(@class, "product-grid-product")]')

product_title=[]
product_price=[]
discount=[]


for product in products:
    product_title.append(product.find_element(by='xpath',value='.//a[@class="product-link _item product-grid-product-info__name link"]').text)
    product_price.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="money-amount__main"]').text)
    discount.append(product.find_element(by='xpath',value='.//span[@class="price-current__discount-percentage"]').text)
   
driver.quit()
                                     
df=pd.DataFrame({'Title':product_title,'Price':product_price, 'Discount':discount})
df.to_csv('Zara_Jackets.csv',index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Does the URL actually return the data you want? Are the XPath expressions correct? Clearly the loop ends up never running.

Comment: Actually, Now I have edited the Product_title XPath. I am able to get the product title in csv. But the issue is product_price and discount. Not sure whether the product price and discount I have selected is correct. Please help me out in this situation

Comment: But then the problem statement is no longer accurate. Can you provide a small fragment of the HTML so that we can see the structure?

Comment: I am trying to inspect this 'https://www.zara.com/us/en/search?searchTerm=women%20jackets&section=WOMAN' page. The issue is I am not able to figure out the price and discount price. Would you be able to find the correct tag

Comment: Attempting to download that URL simply gets me an error message.

Comment: I am voting to reopen, actually question is clear and has enough data for debuggin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You getting empty data, because you don't wait properly for elements to be rendered.

However, to render more elements you need to scroll down until the end, so you should implement continuous scroll and then get all elements data.

Or you can get all data by parsing query that is responsible for rendering (complicated approach, however, more stable).

Query has url part `search/store`, and for it's execution session id is needed.

To make request to contain sessionId param, 2 things are needed:

1. You should be logged in
2. Resource shouldn't detect you as automation browser. (https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)

If 1 or 2 actions wouldn't be done, sessionId would be empty and API request would return 403 without it.

So you log in and start getting network logs, and look for request that contain `search/store` and `session` param.

After you found url, you need to open it and parse body as json. (You can use request lib, but I was unable to get correct response with status 200 even with session param, probably some extra headers needed)

From `json` object you get `totalCount` that represents amount of products and loop through urls, increasing params `offset` and limit.

Limit I set up to 20. API allows limit 200, however, on last iteration in this case it returns not all products (158 from 172).
When I set limit to 20 for each iteration, last iteration result seemed to be correct.

It looks a bit complicated, but if you will understand how it works, parse data from most of sites wouldn't be big deal.

```py
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlunparse, urlencode
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
driver = uc.Chrome(options)
driver.get("https://www.zara.com/us/en/logon")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
time.sleep(2)
geo_consent = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-qa-action=stay-in-store]')
if len(geo_consent) > 0:
    geo_consent[0].click()
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(geo_consent[0]))

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name=logonId'))).send_keys('your mail')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name=password'))).send_keys('yourpass')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-qa-action=logon-form-submit]').click()

driver.get('https://www.zara.com/us/en/search?searchTerm=women%20jackets&section=WOMAN')
driver.maximize_window()
products = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/li[contains(@class, "product-grid-product")]')))

logs = driver.get_log("performance")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Woman']").click()
target_url = "search/store"
time.sleep(2)


def get_store_endpoint():
    for log in logs:
        message = log["message"]
        if "Network.responseReceived" not in message:
            continue
        params = json.loads(message)["message"].get("params")
        if params is None:
            continue
        response = params.get("response")
        if response is None or target_url not in response["url"]:
            continue
        parsed_endpoint = urlparse(response['url'])
        query_params = parse_qs(parsed_endpoint.query)
        if 'session' in query_params:
            return response['url']


product_title = []
product_price = []
discount = []
endpoint = get_store_endpoint()
parsed_endpoint = urlparse(endpoint)
query_params = parse_qs(parsed_endpoint.query)
limit_per_request = 20
offset = 0

driver.get(endpoint)
response = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').text
total_count = json.loads(response)['totalResults']

while offset < total_count:
    parsed_endpoint = urlparse(endpoint)
    query_params = parse_qs(parsed_endpoint.query)
    if total_count - offset <= limit_per_request:
        limit_per_request = total_count - offset
    query_params['offset'] = [f"{offset}"]
    query_params['limit'] = [f"{limit_per_request}"]
    endpoint = urlunparse(parsed_endpoint._replace(query=urlencode(query_params, doseq=True)))
    offset += limit_per_request

    driver.get(endpoint)

    response = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').text
    results = json.loads(response)['results']
    for product in results:
        content = product['content']
        product_title.append(content['name'])
        price = 'No price'
        product_discount = 'No discount'
        if 'price' in content:
            price = content['price'] / 100
        if 'oldPrice' in content:
            product_discount = (content['oldPrice'] - content['price']) / 100
        product_price.append(price)
        discount.append(product_discount)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': product_title, 'Price': product_price, 'Discount': discount})
df.to_csv('Zara_Jackets.csv', index=False)

print(df)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: @Yaroslavm..Thanl you so much. It was great help !!! Thanks once again.:)

Comment: Well the code is accurate  and defined precisely. It rendering the steps as required. Since I am not much aware about JSON, still learning in bits and bytes. Just wanted to now, If I want to get the discount, color and sizes of these products. Where and how can I add the respective tags.

Comment: @archana you can investigate their JSON and find all needed info for you (I guess it is present in `content` object. To investigate JSON open Chrome dev tools, open Network tab, open link, open Fetch / XHR tab, find query, click on it and open preview tab.

Here is an video how to investigate response in Network tab: https://monosnap.com/file/6SQF9OCoMFHBzVyNMisREQmDAOoDFd

Comment: for example colors array is placed inside content by path `content['detail']['colors']`

Comment: When I try to pull the data from['colors] , I am getting all the data such as '[{'id': '800', 'productId': 308627259, 'name': 'Black', 'stylingId': '010',....etc. Unable to filter only color. wrt to Size, its located in another key called 'Facets'

Comment: product_title.append(content['name'])
        price = 'No price'
        product_discount = 'No discount'
        if 'price' in content:
            price = content['price'] / 100
        if 'oldPrice' in content:
            product_discount = (content['oldPrice'] - content['price']) / 100
        product_price.append(price)
        discount.append(product_discount)
        product_color.append(content['detail']['colors'])
    facets = json.loads(response)['facets']
    for product in facets:
        size = product['sizes_facet']
        product_size.append(size['id'])